# Database ER Model weekday availability

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I've got a annoying design issue when designing a database and it's models. Essentially, the database got clients and customers which should be able to make appointments with eachother. The clients should have their availability (on a general week basis) stored in the database, and this needs to be added to the appointment model. The solution does not require or want precise hours for the availability, just one value for each day - ranging from "not available", to "maybe available " to "available". The only solution i've come up with so far includes having all 7 days stored in a row for each client, but it looks nasty.

So here's some of what I got so far:

```
Client model:
   ClientId
   Service,
   Fee

Customer-that-uses-Client model:
   CustomerId 
   ServiceNeed

Availability-model:
   ClientID (FK/PK)
   Monday, (int)
   ...
   ...
   Sunday (int)
```

And finally, appointment model:

```
AppointmentId
ClientID
CustomerID
StartDate
Hourse
```

Problem: is there any way i can redesign the avilability model to ... well, need less fields and still get each day stored with a (1-3) value depending on the clients availability ? Would also be really good if the appointment model wouldnt need to reference all that data from the availability model...

Comment: Don't include mathematical operators in table/column identifiers

Comment: What about, once the Appointment is made ... which makes the ClientId & Day unavailable for other Appointments ?

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

Answering the narrow question is easy.  However, noting the `Relational Database` tag, there are a few problems in your model, that render it somewhat less than Relational.

- Eg. the data content in each logical row needs to be unique.  (Uniqueness on the `Record id`, which is physical, system-generated, and not from the data, cannot provide row uniqueness.)  The Primary Key must be "made up from the data", which is of course the only way to make the data row unique.
- Eg. values such as `Day` of availability and `AvailabilityType` are not constrained, and they need to be.

### Relational Data Model

With the issues fixed, the answer looks like this:

[image: OleTA]

#### Notation

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993.
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for those who are new to the *Relational Model* or data modelling.

#### Content

In the *Relational Model*, there is a large emphasis on constraining the data, such that the database as a whole contains only valid data.

- > The only solution i've come up with so far includes having all 7 days stored in a row for each client, but it looks nasty.

  - Yes.  What you had was a repeating attribute (they are named Monday..Sunday, which may not look like a repeating attribute, but it is one, no less than a CSV list).  That breaks Codd's **Second Normal Form**.
  - The solution is to place the single element in a subordinate table `ProviderAvailable`.
- `Day` of availability and `AvailabilityType` are now constrained to a set of values.
- The rows in `Provider` (sorry, the use of "Client" in this context grates on me) and `Customer` are now unique, due to addition of a `Name`.  The users will not use an internal number to identify such entities, they will use a name, usually a ShortName.

  - Once the model is tightened up, and all the columns are defined, if `Name` (not a combination of LastName, FirstName, Initial) is unique, you can eliminate the `RecordId`, and elevate the `Name` AK to the PK.

#### Not Modelled

You have not asked, and I have not modelled these items, but I suspect they will come up as you progress in the development.

- A Provider (Client) provides 1 Service.  There may be more than 1 in future.
- A Customer, seeking 1 Service, can make an Appointment with any Provider (who may or may not provide that Service).  You may want to constrain each Appointment to a Provider who provides the sought Service.
- As per my comment.  It depends on how tight you want this Availability/Reservation system to be.  Right now, there is nothing to prevent more than one Customer reserving one Provider on a particular Day, ie. a double-booking.

---

Answer (score 1):

Normalize that `availability` table:  instead of

ClientID (FK/PK)
   Monday, (int)
   ...
   ...
   Sunday (int)

go with

ClientID                                        (PK/FK)
   weekday        integer value (0-6 or maybe 1-7) (PK)
   availability   integer value 1-3

This table has a compound primary key, made of `(ClientID, weekday)` because each client may have either zero or one entry for each of the seven weekdays.

In this table, you might have these rows:

```
 43    2    3      (on Tuesdays = 2, client 43 is Available =3)
 43    3    2      (on Wednesdays = 3, client 43 is MaybeAvailable =2)
```

If the row is missing, it means the client is unavailable.  an availability value of 1 also means that.